# "Trust you to do ...!" in French

Tags: expressions

> **Trust you to** be punctual, turning up well into a meeting!

This colloquial expression is used here to point out sarcastically that he has arrived with typical *punctuality*; he can be predictably *trusted* to be always late for an appointment.

This is where AmE speakers might say "**Leave it to you to** be punctual, ..." instead, I suppose? How do French speakers commonly express this idea?

Comment: I guess you mean "he can be predictably trusted to be always early for an appointment" ? There is a bit of a contradiction with the example.

Comment: @Greg No, that is the opposite! This is a sarcastic statement, as indicated by the words in italics. :) This colloquial expression is almost always used to refer to someone's chronic bad habit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some common phrases may express the same idea:

> > Comme d'habitude
> >
> > Comme toujours
> >
> > Fidèle à toi/vous/lui/elle-même
> >
> > Fidèle à ma/ta/sa réputation

So in your example:

> > Comme d'habitude, tu es à l'heure
> >
> > Comme toujours, tu es à l'heure
> >
> > Fidèle à toi-même, tu es à l'heure
> >
> > Fidèle à ta réputation, tu es à l'heure

The first two are more common, the last two are more "sophisticated", and may be used with a sarcastic tone (especially if used to point out a negative habit with some irony).

Comment: Aussi: *Je vois qu'on peut toujours compter toi pour être à l'heure !*

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, something along those lines. I was wondering if French speakers use some fixed structure for this, just like "Trust you to ..." in English.

Comment: There is also *...on peut te faire confiance pour...* which is close to your first sentence.

Comment: I strongly doubt *à l'heure prévue* would be understood as being sarcastic. Maybe *tu te pointes à l'heure qui te plait, trente minutes...* or *tu débarques comme ça, trente minutes après...*

Comment: @jlliagre Sorry, I haven't made myself perfectly clear. What I wanted to ask you is whether the two phrases in bold work well as the equivalents of the idiomatic English expression "Trust you to do ...!". I only meant "à l'heure (prévue)" as a secondary point.

Comment: Oh, then *on te reconnaît bien là !* and *c'est bien toi, ça !* meaning are equivalent. The latter is probably closer to the English tone.